# How to solve org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

What I am trying to achieve is to find the available vehicles by comparing time stamps in the database.so When I execute the following query it gives the following runtime exception SQL GrammerException. But I can't identify any direct syntax issue in this query.Please help me to solve this issue thank you in advance.

**Query**

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT id From VEHICLE WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM VEHICLE_BOOKING  WHERE  (HIRE_DATE_TIME <= ?1 AND RETURN_DATE_TIME >= ?1) OR (RETURN_DATE_TIME < ?2 AND RETURN_DATE_TIME >= ?2 )  OR ( ?1 <= HIRE_DATE_TIME AND ?2 >= RETURN_DATE_TIME) )",nativeQuery = true)
    List<Vehicle> checkAvailability( Date hireDateTime,Date returnDateTime);
```

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [SELECT id From VEHICLE WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM VEHICLE_BOOKING  WHERE  (HIRE_DATE_TIME <= ? AND RETURN_DATE_TIME >= ?) OR (RETURN_DATE_TIME < ? AND RETURN_DATE_TIME >= ? )  OR ( ? <= HIRE_DATE_TIME AND ? >= RETURN_DATE_TIME) )]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:281)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.checkAvailability(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.checkAvailability(Unknown Source)
    at com.banger.rentalmanagementsystem.controller.CustomerController.showUserProfile(CustomerController.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2890)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2869)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2701)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2696)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2142)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1163)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:126)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor$QueryMethodInvoker.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:195)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "ac" not found [42122-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.getColumnIndex(JdbcResultSet.java:3195)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.get(JdbcResultSet.java:3268)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.getString(JdbcResultSet.java:316)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getString(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3088)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1907)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1835)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1808)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1660)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:745)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:995)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:964)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2887)
    ... 88 more
```

Comment: You are selecting only `id` but map with `List<Vehicle>` ?

Comment: @Rono thank you very much for your help, I corrected my mistake

Answer (score 1):

You need to return list of objects not list of ids, so you query should be something like this

```
@Query(value = "SELECT v From VEHICLE AS v WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM VEHICLE_BOOKING  WHERE  (HIRE_DATE_TIME <= ?1 AND RETURN_DATE_TIME >= ?1) OR (RETURN_DATE_TIME < ?2 AND RETURN_DATE_TIME >= ?2 )  OR ( ?1 <= HIRE_DATE_TIME AND ?2 >= RETURN_DATE_TIME) )",nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: @Sinisa90 Thank you very much for you help , I corrected my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Syntax bcuz you select the only id to map a List,

Btw, I recommend that avoid using nativeQuery which lost benefit of JPA

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it's hard to perform join queries with jpql or hql